# solr not picking up any libraries when i specify <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar"/> in solrconfig.xml

Tags: search, solr

Solr is not picking up jar files when i use `<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar"/>` in solrconfig.xml

Also i have created lib directory in solr/ and specified `<lib dir="./lib" />` in solrconfig.xml but it does not pick up the custom jar files.

any idea what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the lib folder in the solr directory the path would be `<lib dir="../lib" />` as relative to the solrconfig.xml it has to jump one directory back to refer to the lib folder.

Comment: My `solrconfig.xml` resides in  `server/solr/test.core/conf/solrconfig.xml`, with a property as
`<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/server/solr/test.core/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />`.
And my jars are contained in `<solr.untarred.dir>/server/solr/test.core/lib/`, but still it is unable to load a class contained in one of the jars. Any clue why?